# Laravel 5.6: Create database and several schemas

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I want to create a database using a command. I am using postgresql. I am creating the tables using the migrations but before that I want to create the database and several schemas.

I am using this command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class pgsql extends Command
{
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'pgsql:createdb {name?}';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Create a new pgsql database schema based on the database config file';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    $dbname = env('DB_DATABASE');
    $dbuser = env('DB_USERNAME');
    $dbpass = env('DB_PASSWORD');
    $dbhost = env('DB_HOST');

    try {
                $db = new \PDO("pgsql:host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass);
                $test = $db->exec("CREATE DATABASE \"$dbname\" WITH TEMPLATE = template0 encoding = 'UTF8' lc_collate='Spanish_Spain.1252' lc_ctype='Spanish_Spain.1252';");
                if($test === false)
                    throw new \Exception($db->errorInfo()[2]);
                $this->info(sprintf('Successfully created %s database', $dbname));
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception) {
                $this->error(sprintf('Failed to create %s database: %s', $dbname, $exception->getMessage()));
    }

}
}
```

I use: 
`php artisan pgsql:createdb schema_name`

But I get this error:
`PHP fatal error: Cannot declare class App\Console\Commands\pgsql, because the name is already in use.`

It worked good in a new project I just made. But not in my current project.

**EDIT1:** I tried to use `php artisan pgsql:createdb schema_name` and I get `There are no commands defined in the "pgsql" namespace`

But when I use `php artisan config:cache` I get this:
[Error using php config:cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOYLv.jpg)

Like I said, this worked for me in a new project, but not in my current project.

**EDIT2:** It worked, I do not get the last error anymore, but I get this:

`Failed to create  database: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "connect_timeout=30" to address: Unknown server error`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You're more likely to get a positive response if you share some code, specifically what you've tried, and any errors you've come across. Also, some initial research into the topic should be done, such as reading something like https://laravel.io/forum/09-13-2014-create-new-database-and-tables-on-the-fly

Comment: Much better. So the error looks like you already have a `pgsql` class in the  `App\Console\Commands` namespace. Check any other files in the `Commands` folder, make sure the class name is unique, or change it to something else.

Comment: That command is my only file in the `Commands` folder.

Comment: That's odd... Afraid I'm not too familiar with that error message. I'm going to update the tags on your question; get some more visibility on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the `PHP fatal error: Cannot declare class App\Console\Commands\pgsql, because the name is already in use.` you should make sure the class name is unique in the namespace.

On the other hand, a more fit command name (as per Laravel suggests) could be:

`class CreatePostgressDatabase extends Command`

and name your file `CreatePostgressDatabase.php` (needs to match the class name)

If the error persists try running a `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan clear-compiled` to clear and rebuild cached class loaders.

Comment: It worked, now I don´t get that error. But I get this error:
Failed to create  database: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "connect_timeout=30" to address: Unknown server error

Comment: Feel free to mark question as answered to help others and open a new question with the new error. Add the reference link so I can jump for help as well.